# DDD and Spring JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, domain-driven-design

I am starting with DDD and Spring JPA. The conception of separating persistence and domain layers looks and works fine for me but I see there one problem: we are losing lazy loading, am I right? Is it possible to map a domain object with an entity without loading all data of the database?
For the reason, I see that it can be a better idea to stop using one-to-many relationships in entities and aggregations in domain objects. So I ask you about advice. Is it a good idea?
I have a conception to delegate some methods from domain objects to services by stop using aggregation in a domain.

So I want to change sth like that (I omitted unnecessary to understand conception elements). For me, it makes simpler to build business logic because we have access to all objects directly, but we waste resources because we need to load a lot of data from database each time we need some object. :
[image: Model of one-to-many relationships.]

to sth like that. It makes that we can better control which objects we need, but we are losing convenience in the creation of business logic because we need to delegate some methods to services:
[image]

What do you think about it? Is it a good idea or there is a better way to solve the problem. It is a little problematic to load so much data from the database to restore objects to memory.
It is a little confusing for me because I see that the standard conceptions of object-oriented programming are problematic to implement in the application of an external database.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you say that you always have to load the entire database.

You would load just the data of an aggregate,  since a rule is that an aggregate references another by the id.  So in a one to many relationship you have a list of ids.

A repository loads / stores the data of an aggregate.

Comment: Thank you. It is helpful, then there is no problem with loading too many elements of DB if domain object contains only ids. But it means that we lose the convenience of access to the objects. We can't directly invoke the elements of the list. So, for example, what about calculation expiryDate() in Subscription object? Should Subscription has access to persistence layer or it should be done by service? I think that then the work should be done by service. Am I right?